# Error when starting the server setting up the tesseract OCR gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, tesseract

I've installed a tesseract-ocr (0.1.8) gem. Mac OS X El Capitan.

When I do `rails s` an error appears:

```
/Users/tagandev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@bshc_piv/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:94:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'tesseract-ocr'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: compile error: see logs at /var/folders/z8/nsyvk31j6lj6zx7ybmws_sg80000gn/T/.ffi-inline-501/ff2ae5853d8e6c6000319eab14f6c8dc6127a842.log
```

The dependencies are installed:

```
tesseract 3.04.01
  leptonica-1.74.1
   libjpeg 8d: libpng 1.6.28: libtiff 4.0.7: zlib 1.2.5
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I have been facing the same issues with windows